# ResulSet: do {...} while (...); vs. while(...) {...}

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I often see people doing `while(resultSet.next()) {...}` but does not that skip the first row? It switches directly to the next row.

Should not you do instead `do {...} while (resultSet.next());`?

Comment: try accessing the first result before using next() ;).

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not skip the first row.

`next()` is required to be called **before** processing the first row.

So actually,  the `do ... while` solution doesn't work, because then the ResultSet would not positioned properly for the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, Read the [next() java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the **first call to the method next makes the first row the current row**

Answer (score 1):

As per specification:

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row;

So actually the first `next()` will position the cursor to the first line.
See
[official JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

Answer (score 1):

It does not.

`ResultSet` contains an internal cursor, which begins **before** the first element.

If you try to call `resultSet.getString("something")` before moving the cursor from here, it will fail (why not try it).

`while (resultSet.next()) {...}` is the preferred way to iterate through a `ResultSet`